# How to get the size of a Nix derivation?

Tags: nixos, nix

Is it possible to figure out the size of a derivation after building it? For example, after `nixos-rebuild`, how much space does the new derivation take, *excluding any storage savings because of previous builds?*

Comment: One approach: Get a list of dependencies for each, calculate the ones in common and the ones specific to each. And then get the size of each dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
nix-store -q --requisites `nix-build --no-out-link '<nixpkgs>' -A vim` | sort -uf | xargs du -ch | tail -1
```

I also like to look at:

```
for p in /nix/var/nix/profiles/system* /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/$USER/profile*
do
   echo -n $p" ⇒ "
   nix-store -q --requisites $p | sort -uf | xargs du -ch | tail -1
done
```

Obviously the size of the transitive closure of derivations heavily overlap (shared libs, etc.) so the numbers will always add to more than the total space usage. Still useful though.

Comment: This is closer than the other answer, but it doesn't show where the derivations corresponding to the generations listed by `nix-env --list-generations` are stored.

Comment: They're pinned by the symlinks `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/$USER/profile*`

Comment: Oh, nice! That does it, then :) `nix-store -q --requisites /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/$USER/profile-1-link | sort -uf | xargs du -ch | tail -1`

Comment: Or even `for path in /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/$USER/profile-*; do nix-store -q --requisites "$path" | xargs du --si --total | tail --lines=1 | sed "s#total#${path}#"; done`

Answer (score 6):

You may want [`nix path-info`](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/command-ref/new-cli/nix3-path-info.html?) (e.g., for emacs):

```
$ nix-build -A emacs '<nixpkgs>'
$ nix path-info -Sh ./result
/nix/store/3l9lddwxz1mayaxvw8iy50ygzzfh1s1b-emacs-27.2   470.4M
```

From the [Nix release notes](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/release-notes/rl-2.0.html#release-20-2018-02-22):

> `nix path-info` shows information about store paths, replacing `nix-store -q`. A useful feature is the option `--closure-size` (`-S`). For example, the following command show the closure sizes of every path in the current NixOS system closure, sorted by size:
>
> ```
> nix path-info -rS /run/current-system | sort -nk2
> ```

See also the [Nix manual on Installables](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/command-ref/new-cli/nix.html#installables).